# How to push into array and setState for multiple properties in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, single-page-application

I want to set multiple array while inserting items into the array
Can anybody suggest me whats wrong with the code.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { aArr: [], bArr: [], cArr: [] };
    this.someFunction();
  }

  someFunction() {
    let result = [
      { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
      { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }
    ];
    result.forEach((item) => {
      this.setState({
        aArr: [...this.state.aArr, item.a],
        bArr: [...this.state.bArr, item.b],
        cArr: [...this.state.cArr, item.c]
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        aArr: {this.state.aArr}
        bArr: {this.state.bArr}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

final output should be aArr : 1,4
bArr : 2,5

Comment: What are `this.state.af` and `this.state.bf`?  Seems like the question needs some cleanup.

Comment: What's the point of using `setState` inside `constructor`?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set state in a forEach loop. Yet `this.setState()` is async and takes some time to execute. So you are not able to set data in the state. You need to update your result in some other variable then you can set that data in your state. Here's how you can do it-

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { aArr: [], bArr: [], cArr: [] };

    let result = [
        { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
        { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }
    ];

    const {aArr, bArr, cArr} = this.state

    result.map(res => {
        aArr.push(res.a)
        bArr.push(res.b)
        cArr.push(res.c)
    })

    this.setState({aArr, bArr, cArr});

  } 
  render() {
    return <div>aArr: {this.state.aArr.join(', ')} <br/>
    bArr: {this.state.bArr.join(', ')}</div>;
  }
}
```

You can [find the working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-spdhva)

Comment: thanks brother, its working fine. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: one more doubt? what if i want to push only unique values. i am using this: aArr = aArr.indexOf( item ) === -1 ? aArr.push( item.a) : aArr; bArr = bArr.indexOf( item ) === -1 ? bArr.push( item.b) : aArr; but the loop is running only once.

Comment: You can use `includes` method of array to check if that is already included in array or not. Like - `if(!aArr.includes(a)) {aArr.push(res.a)}`

Comment: thanks brother, all fixed.

Comment: Cool. Will be great if you could mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer